# Fp-growth algorithm in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to code the fp growth Algorithm in PHP Codeigneter  .it worked fine with small data set(array)but it gave me an error with large data set it shows some of frequent item sets(output)but shows also this  ."Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"."Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in models\Algorithm.php on line 119"

in the models

`class Algorithm extends CI_Model{`

```
public function find_frequent_itemsets($transactions, $minimum_support){

    $processedTransactions = array();
    $items = array();
    //var_dump($transactions);
    foreach($transactions as $transaction){
        if(!is_array($transaction)) 
            continue;
        $processed = array();

        foreach($transaction as $item){

            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                $items[$item] += 1;
            }else{

                $items[$item] = 1;
            }
            array_push($processed, $item);

        }// every transaction.

        array_push($processedTransactions, $processed);
    }

      foreach(array_keys($items) as $index){
        if($items[$index] < $minimum_support){
            unset($items[$index]);
        }
    }



    $sortedTransactions = array();
    //var_dump($processedTransactions);
    foreach($processedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tmp = array();

        foreach($currentTransactions as $item){
            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                // key exits = frequent item.
                //array_push($tmp, array($item, $items[$item]));
                $tmp[$item] = $items[$item];
            }
        }

        // sort based on most frequent item.
        arsort($tmp);
        //var_dump($tmp);
        array_push($sortedTransactions, array_keys($tmp));
    }

    //var_dump($sortedTransactions);
    // Create a Fp-Tree
    $tree = new FPTree();

    // Add all Transactions.
    foreach($sortedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tree->add($currentTransactions);
    }




        for itemset in find_with_suffix(master, []):
            yield itemset


    foreach(find_with_suffix($tree, array(), $minimum_support) as $itemset){
        yield $itemset;
    }

}// end function`}`


function find_with_suffix($tree, $suffix, $minimum_support){
/* $element = ($item, $nodes)
   $item is the item it self like (a, b, ..., e)
   $nodes is the linked list for that item (e1 -> e2 -> e3 .... ) */
  foreach($tree->getItems() as $element){
    $item = $element[0];
    $nodes = $element[1];
    $support = 0;
    /* calculate support of each linked list. */
    foreach($nodes as $n){
        $support += $n->getCount();
    }

    if($support >= $minimum_support && !array_key_exists($item, $suffix)){
        $found_set = array_merge(array($item), $suffix);
        /* yields current found set */
        yield $found_set;




$condTree =  conditional_tree_from_paths($tree->prefixPaths($item),$minimum_support);


            foreach(find_with_suffix($condTree, $found_set, $minimum_support) as $s){
            yield $s;
        }
    }
}}function conditional_tree_from_paths($paths, $minimum_support){

$tree = new FPTree();
$conditionItem = null;
$items = array();

foreach($paths as $path){
    if($conditionItem == null){
        $conditionItem = end($path)->getItem();
        //reset($path);
    }

    $point = $tree->root;

    foreach($path as $node){
        //next_point = point.search(node.item)
        $nextPoint = $point->search($node->getItem());

        if($nextPoint == null){
            // Add a new node to the tree.
            array_push($items, $node->getItem());
            $count = ($node->getItem() == $conditionItem) ? $node->getCount() : 0;
            $nextPoint = new FPNode($tree, $node->getItem(), $count);
            $point->add($nextPoint);
            $tree->updateRoute($nextPoint);
        }
        $point = $nextPoint;
    }
}

// assert condition_item is not None
foreach($tree->prefixPaths($conditionItem) as $path){
    $count = end($path)->getCount();
    //reset($path);
    foreach(array_reverse(array_slice($path, 0, count($path) - 1)) as $node){
        $tmpCount = $node->getCount();
        $node->setCount($tmpCount + $count);
    }
}

// as set.
$items = array_unique($items);


foreach($items as $item){

    $currentSupport = 0;
    foreach($tree->getNodes($item) as $n){
        $currentSupport += $n->getCount();
    }

    if($currentSupport < $minimum_support){
        foreach($tree->getNodes($item) as $n){
            $parent = $n->getParent();
            if($parent != null){
                $parent->remove($n);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove leaves .
foreach($tree->getNodes($conditionItem) as $node){
    $parent = $node->getParent();
    if($parent != null){
        $parent->remove($node);
    }
}

return $tree;}class FPNode {
var $tree;
var $item;
var $count;
var $parent;
var $children;
var $neighbor;

/**
 * @param $tree
 * @param $item
 * @param int $count
 */
public function __construct($tree, $item, $count=1){
    $this->tree = $tree;
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->count = $count;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->children = array();
    $this->neighbor = null;
}

/**
 * @param $child
 */
public function add($child){
    $item = $child->getItem();
    if(!array_key_exists($item, $this->children)){
        $child->setParent($this);
        $this->children[$item] = $child;
    }
}


/**
 * @param $item
 * @return null
 */
public function search($item){
    //return array_key_exists($item, $this->children);
    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->children)){
        return $this->children[$item];
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * @param $child
 */
public function remove($child){
    $item = $child->getItem();
    if($this->search($item)){
        unset($this->children[$item]);
        $child->setParent(null);
        //self._tree._removed(child)
        $this->tree->removed($child);
        foreach($child->getChildren() as $sub_child){
            $sub_item = $sub_child->getItem();
            if($this->search($sub_item)){
                // self._children[sub_child.item]._count += sub_child.count
                $currentCount = $this->children[$sub_child->getItem()]->getCount();
                $subCount = $sub_child->getCount();
                $this->children[$sub_child->getItem()]->setCount($currentCount + $subCount);
                $sub_child->setParent(null);
            }else{
                $this->add($sub_child);
            }
        }
        $child->setChildren(null);
    }
}

/**
 *
 */
public function increment(){
    $this->count++;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isRoot(){
    return $this->item == null && $this->count == null;
}
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTree()
{
    return $this->tree;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $tree
 */
public function setTree($tree)
{
    $this->tree = $tree;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getItem()
{
    return $this->item;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $item
 */
public function setItem($item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getCount()
{
    return $this->count;
}

/**
 * @param int $count
 */
public function setCount($count)
{
    $this->count = $count;
}

/**
 * @return null
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param null $parent
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

/**
 * @return null
 */
public function getNeighbor()
{
    return $this->neighbor;
}

/**
 * @param null $neighbor
 */
public function setNeighbor($neighbor)
{
    $this->neighbor = $neighbor;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}

/**
 * @param array $children
 */
public function setChildren($children)
{
    $this->children = $children;
}}class FPTree {

var $root;
var $routes;

public function __construct(){
    $this->root = new FPNode($this, null, null);
    // Item -> (head, tail)
    $this->routes = array();
}

public function add($transaction){
    $point = $this->root;

    foreach($transaction as $item){
        $nextPoint = $point->search($item);

        if($nextPoint != null){
            $nextPoint->increment();
        }else{
            // Null
            $nextPoint = new FPNode($this, $item, 1);
            $point->add($nextPoint);
            $this->updateRoute($nextPoint);
        }

        $point = $nextPoint;
    }
}

public function updateRoute($point){
    $item = $point->getItem();

    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){
        $route = $this->routes[$item];
        $route[1]->setNeighbor($point);
        $this->routes[$item] = array($route[0], $point);
    }else{
        // $item not found.
        // add new pair with the same item.
        // used as linked list but (head, tail) only.
        $this->routes[$item] = array($point, $point);
    }
}

public function getItems(){
    $items = array();
    foreach(array_keys($this->routes) as $item){
        array_push($items, array($item, $this->getNodes($item)));
    }

    return $items;
}

public function getNodes($item){

    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){

        $node = $this->routes[$item][0];
        $nodes = array();


        while($node != null){
            array_push($nodes, $node);
            $node = $node->getNeighbor();
        }
        return $nodes;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

public function getPath($node){
    $path = array();
    while($node != null && !$node->isRoot()){
        array_push($path, $node);
        $node = $node->getParent();
    }
    return array_reverse($path);
}

public function prefixPaths($item){
    $paths = array();

    foreach($this->getNodes($item) as $node){
        array_push($paths, $this->getPath($node));
    }

    return $paths;
}

public function removed($node){
    $item = $node->getItem();
    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){
        $route = $this->routes[$item];

        $head = $route[0];
        $tail = $route[1];

        if($node == $head){
            if($node == $tail || $node != $node->getNeighbor()){
                unset($this->routes[$item]);
            }else{

                $this->routes[$item] = array($node->getNeighbor(), $tail);
            }
        }else{

            $nodes = $this->getNodes($item);
            foreach($nodes as $n){
                // if n.neighbor is node:
                if($n->getNeighbor() == $node){
                    $n->setNeighbor($node->getNeighbor());
                    if($node == $tail){
                        $this->routes[$item] = array($head, $n);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public function printTree(){
    echo "Tree\n";
    echo "Root";
    $this->inspect($this->root, 0);
}

public function inspect($node, $level){
    for($i = 0; $i < $level; ++$i){
        echo '..';
    }
    if($node != null){


        echo "(". $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ")" . " ==> ";
        foreach($node->getChildren() as $child){
            echo "(" . $child->getItem() . ":" . $child->getCount() . "), ";
        }
        echo "\n";
        foreach($node->getChildren() as $child){
            $this->inspect($child, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

public function printNeighbors($item){
    $nodes = $this->getNodes($item);

    if($nodes != null){
        foreach($nodes as $node){
            echo "(" . $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ") -> ";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}

public function printAllPrefix($item){
    $paths = $this->prefixPaths($item);

    foreach($paths as $path){
        foreach($path as $node){
            echo "(" . $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ") -> ";
        }

        echo "\n";
    }
}

public function getRoot()
{
    return $this->root;
}


public function setRoot($root)
{
    $this->root = $root;
}


public function getRoutes()
{
    return $this->routes;
}


public function setRoutes ($routes)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
}

 }
```

in controller

```
 $transactions=$this->Getdata->getdataset();
$minimum_support = 2;
foreach($this->algorithm->find_frequent_itemsets($transactions,$minimum_support) as $itemset){                     
        echo '{' . implode(", ", $itemset) . '}' . "\n";
             }
```

Comment: are you asking what the meaning of the error message is (you script needs more time to finish than your php settings allow) or why your script needs that much time?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors I think. First is the script timing out at 30 seconds which you can fix simply with this line at the top of your script

```
set_time_limit(0); //0 means unlimited
```

Second is a warning that something you are trying to loop isnt an array or object. Your data set possibly has an empty sub array somewhere. You can resolve this by wrapping your foreach loops in

```
if(is_array($array)){ //or is_object() if you expect an object
    //do foreach in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Algorithm {

public function find_frequent_itemsets($transactions, $minimum_support){

    $processedTransactions = array();
    $items = array();
    //var_dump($transactions);
    foreach($transactions as $transaction){
        if(!is_array($transaction)) 
            continue;
        $processed = array();

        foreach($transaction as $item){

            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                $items[$item] += 1;
            }else{

                $items[$item] = 1;
            }
            array_push($processed, $item);

        }// every transaction.

        array_push($processedTransactions, $processed);
    }

      foreach(array_keys($items) as $index){
        if($items[$index] < $minimum_support){
            unset($items[$index]);
        }
    }



    $sortedTransactions = array();
    //var_dump($processedTransactions);
    foreach($processedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tmp = array();

        foreach($currentTransactions as $item){
            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                // key exits = frequent item.
                //array_push($tmp, array($item, $items[$item]));
                $tmp[$item] = $items[$item];
            }
        }

        // sort based on most frequent item.
        arsort($tmp);
        //var_dump($tmp);
        array_push($sortedTransactions, array_keys($tmp));
    }

    //var_dump($sortedTransactions);
    // Create a Fp-Tree
    $tree = new FPTree();

    // Add all Transactions.
    foreach($sortedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tree->add($currentTransactions);
    }




        for itemset in find_with_suffix(master, []):
            yield itemset


    foreach(find_with_suffix($tree, array(), $minimum_support) as $itemset){
        yield $itemset;
    }

}// end function`}`


function find_with_suffix($tree, $suffix, $minimum_support){
/* $element = ($item, $nodes)
   $item is the item it self like (a, b, ..., e)
   $nodes is the linked list for that item (e1 -> e2 -> e3 .... ) */
  foreach($tree->getItems() as $element){
    $item = $element[0];
    $nodes = $element[1];
    $support = 0;
    /* calculate support of each linked list. */
    foreach($nodes as $n){
        $support += $n->getCount();
    }

    if($support >= $minimum_support && !array_key_exists($item, $suffix)){
        $found_set = array_merge(array($item), $suffix);
        /* yields current found set */
        yield $found_set;




$condTree =  conditional_tree_from_paths($tree->prefixPaths($item),$minimum_support);


            foreach(find_with_suffix($condTree, $found_set, $minimum_support) as $s){
            yield $s;
        }
    }
}}function conditional_tree_from_paths($paths, $minimum_support){

$tree = new FPTree();
$conditionItem = null;
$items = array();

foreach($paths as $path){
    if($conditionItem == null){
        $conditionItem = end($path)->getItem();
        //reset($path);
    }

    $point = $tree->root;

    foreach($path as $node){
        //next_point = point.search(node.item)
        $nextPoint = $point->search($node->getItem());

        if($nextPoint == null){
            // Add a new node to the tree.
            array_push($items, $node->getItem());
            $count = ($node->getItem() == $conditionItem) ? $node->getCount() : 0;
            $nextPoint = new FPNode($tree, $node->getItem(), $count);
            $point->add($nextPoint);
            $tree->updateRoute($nextPoint);
        }
        $point = $nextPoint;
    }
}

// assert condition_item is not None
foreach($tree->prefixPaths($conditionItem) as $path){
    $count = end($path)->getCount();
    //reset($path);
    foreach(array_reverse(array_slice($path, 0, count($path) - 1)) as $node){
        $tmpCount = $node->getCount();
        $node->setCount($tmpCount + $count);
    }
}

// as set.
$items = array_unique($items);
if (is_array($items) || is_object($items)){

foreach($items as $item){

    $currentSupport = 0;
    foreach($tree->getNodes($item) as $n){
        $currentSupport += $n->getCount();
    }

    if($currentSupport < $minimum_support){



        foreach($tree->getNodes($item) as $n){
            $parent = $n->getParent();
            if($parent != null){
                $parent->remove($n);
            }
        }


    }
}
}
// Remove leaves .
foreach($tree->getNodes($conditionItem) as $node){
    $parent = $node->getParent();
    if($parent != null){
        $parent->remove($node);
    }
}

return $tree;}

}
class FPNode {
var $tree;
var $item;
var $count;
var $parent;
var $children;
var $neighbor;

/**
 * @param $tree
 * @param $item
 * @param int $count
 */
public function __construct($tree, $item, $count=1){
    $this->tree = $tree;
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->count = $count;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->children = array();
    $this->neighbor = null;
}

/**
 * @param $child
 */
public function add($child){
    $item = $child->getItem();
    if(!array_key_exists($item, $this->children)){
        $child->setParent($this);
        $this->children[$item] = $child;
    }
}


/**
 * @param $item
 * @return null
 */
public function search($item){
    //return array_key_exists($item, $this->children);
    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->children)){
        return $this->children[$item];
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * @param $child
 */
public function remove($child){
    $item = $child->getItem();
    if($this->search($item)){
        unset($this->children[$item]);
        $child->setParent(null);
        //self._tree._removed(child)
        $this->tree->removed($child);
        foreach($child->getChildren() as $sub_child){
            $sub_item = $sub_child->getItem();
            if($this->search($sub_item)){
                // self._children[sub_child.item]._count += sub_child.count
                $currentCount = $this->children[$sub_child->getItem()]->getCount();
                $subCount = $sub_child->getCount();
                $this->children[$sub_child->getItem()]->setCount($currentCount + $subCount);
                $sub_child->setParent(null);
            }else{
                $this->add($sub_child);
            }
        }
        $child->setChildren(null);
    }
}

/**
 *
 */
public function increment(){
    $this->count++;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isRoot(){
    return $this->item == null && $this->count == null;
}
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTree()
{
    return $this->tree;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $tree
 */
public function setTree($tree)
{
    $this->tree = $tree;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getItem()
{
    return $this->item;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $item
 */
public function setItem($item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getCount()
{
    return $this->count;
}

/**
 * @param int $count
 */
public function setCount($count)
{
    $this->count = $count;
}

/**
 * @return null
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param null $parent
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

/**
 * @return null
 */
public function getNeighbor()
{
    return $this->neighbor;
}

/**
 * @param null $neighbor
 */
public function setNeighbor($neighbor)
{
    $this->neighbor = $neighbor;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}

/**
 * @param array $children
 */
public function setChildren($children)
{
    $this->children = $children;
}}class FPTree {

var $root;
var $routes;

public function __construct(){
    $this->root = new FPNode($this, null, null);
    // Item -> (head, tail)
    $this->routes = array();
}

public function add($transaction){
    $point = $this->root;

    foreach($transaction as $item){
        $nextPoint = $point->search($item);

        if($nextPoint != null){
            $nextPoint->increment();
        }else{
            // Null
            $nextPoint = new FPNode($this, $item, 1);
            $point->add($nextPoint);
            $this->updateRoute($nextPoint);
        }

        $point = $nextPoint;
    }
}

public function updateRoute($point){
    $item = $point->getItem();

    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){
        $route = $this->routes[$item];
        $route[1]->setNeighbor($point);
        $this->routes[$item] = array($route[0], $point);
    }else{
        // $item not found.
        // add new pair with the same item.
        // used as linked list but (head, tail) only.
        $this->routes[$item] = array($point, $point);
    }
}

public function getItems(){
    $items = array();
    foreach(array_keys($this->routes) as $item){
        array_push($items, array($item, $this->getNodes($item)));
    }

    return $items;
}

public function getNodes($item){

    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){

        $node = $this->routes[$item][0];
        $nodes = array();


        while($node != null){
            array_push($nodes, $node);
            $node = $node->getNeighbor();
        }
        return $nodes;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

public function getPath($node){
    $path = array();
    while($node != null && !$node->isRoot()){
        array_push($path, $node);
        $node = $node->getParent();
    }
    return array_reverse($path);
}

public function prefixPaths($item){
    $paths = array();

    foreach($this->getNodes($item) as $node){
        array_push($paths, $this->getPath($node));
    }

    return $paths;
}

public function removed($node){
    $item = $node->getItem();
    if(array_key_exists($item, $this->routes)){
        $route = $this->routes[$item];

        $head = $route[0];
        $tail = $route[1];

        if($node == $head){
            if($node == $tail || $node != $node->getNeighbor()){
                unset($this->routes[$item]);
            }else{

                $this->routes[$item] = array($node->getNeighbor(), $tail);
            }
        }else{

            $nodes = $this->getNodes($item);
            foreach($nodes as $n){
                // if n.neighbor is node:
                if($n->getNeighbor() == $node){
                    $n->setNeighbor($node->getNeighbor());
                    if($node == $tail){
                        $this->routes[$item] = array($head, $n);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public function printTree(){
    echo "Tree\n";
    echo "Root";
    $this->inspect($this->root, 0);
}

public function inspect($node, $level){
    for($i = 0; $i < $level; ++$i){
        echo '..';
    }
    if($node != null){


        echo "(". $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ")" . " ==> ";
        foreach($node->getChildren() as $child){
            echo "(" . $child->getItem() . ":" . $child->getCount() . "), ";
        }
        echo "\n";
        foreach($node->getChildren() as $child){
            $this->inspect($child, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

public function printNeighbors($item){
    $nodes = $this->getNodes($item);

    if($nodes != null){
        foreach($nodes as $node){
            echo "(" . $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ") -> ";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}

public function printAllPrefix($item){
    $paths = $this->prefixPaths($item);

    foreach($paths as $path){
        foreach($path as $node){
            echo "(" . $node->getItem() . ":" . $node->getCount() . ") -> ";
        }

        echo "\n";
    }
}

public function getRoot()
{
    return $this->root;
}


public function setRoot($root)
{
    $this->root = $root;
}


public function getRoutes()
{
    return $this->routes;
}


public function setRoutes ($routes)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
}

 }

 ?>

 <?php 

 $transactions['0']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['0']['1']="LAPTOP";
 $transactions['0']['2']="TV";

 $transactions['1']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['1']['1']="TV";

 $transactions['2']['0']="MOUSE";
 $transactions['2']['1']="REMOTE";
 $transactions['2']['2']="UPS";

 $transactions['3']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['3']['1']="LAPTOP";
 $transactions['3']['2']="UPS";

 $transactions['4']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['4']['1']="LAPTOP";
 $transactions['4']['2']="TV";

 $transactions['5']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['5']['1']="LAPTOP";
 $transactions['5']['2']="MOUSE";
 $transactions['5']['3']="TV";

 $transactions['6']['0']="KEYBOARD";
 $transactions['6']['1']="STABILIZER";

 $transactions['7']['0']="MOUSE";
 $transactions['7']['1']="UPS";

 $transactions['8']['0']="REMOTE";
 $transactions['8']['1']="UPS";

 $transactions['9']['0']="AC";
 $transactions['9']['1']="LAPTOP";
 $transactions['9']['2']="MOUSE";
 $transactions['9']['3']="TV";

 $aa=new Algorithm();
 $minimum_support = 2;
 foreach($aa->find_frequent_itemsets($transactions,$minimum_support) as $itemset){
    echo '{' . implode(", ", $itemset) . '}' . "\n";
 }

 ?>
```